# Blazor Web Assembly Calling OpenIDConnect from Service

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to refactor my Blazor Web Assembly Core Hosted (.net 7) app and put everything into services (to keep from having fat controllers).  One thing I am having a hard time with is how to manage the SSO process (using OpenIDConnect).  The way I have done it in the past is to redirect the user to the url and use a Login.cshtml.cs file to initiaiate the challenge.  Is there a way to do this all through APIs?  Here is my psuedo code setup:

**Login Component Button Event**:

```
await authStateProvider.Login()
```

**IdentityAuthenticationStateProvider: AuthenticationStateProvider**

```
private readonly IAuthorizeApi _authorize;
public async Task Login(){
   await _autorize.login();
   NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync(); 
}
```

**AuthorizeApi:IAuthorizeApi**

```
public AuthorizeApi(HttpClient httpClient){
   _httpClient = httpClient;
}

public async Task Login(LoginParameters params){
   //Make the challenge here and get the response back (i.e. claims) from the external Identity Server
}
```

All the examples I have seen are for using Username/Passwords.  the Login method would use those to authenticate the user and return the claims, using Identity, but I am not using Username/Password.  Instead, I have an external identity provider and I use OpenIDConnect (oidc) to authenticate the user, return claims from that authentication, and then get the users info from the application's Identity tables.

Currently, I can authenticate like this:

**myApp.Server Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options=>{
  //set defaults
}).addCookies("cookie", =>options{
//set defaults
}).AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options=>{
  options.ClientId= "abc";
  options.ClientSecrte = "xyz";
  options.Authority = "someURL";
  //etc.
});
```

Thanks!